# How to show selected data in combo menu

Tags: php

im create dynamic combo from databases and wanna show selected data after in edit menu this my code

```
<select class="form-control" id="id_prog" name="id_prog"  placeholder="Program">
    <option>-- Program --</option>
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("select * from program order by program asc");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        ?><option value="<?php echo $row['id_prog']; ?>"><?php echo $row['program']; ?></option><?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: First of all, you should think about using `mysqli` instead of the procedular `mysql` style. `mysql` is deprecated with PHP7 and will no longer be supported. Second, what is your problem with this code?

Comment: Thx for advice alex, sure ill use that after this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your current requirement, the **solution code** would be like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="id_prog" name="id_prog"  placeholder="Program">
    <option>-- Program --</option>
    <?php 
        $query=mysql_query("select * from program order by program asc");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $output = '<option value="' . $row['id_prog'] . '"';
            if($row['id_prog'] == YOUR_DESIRED_VALUE){
                $output .= ' selected="selected"';
            }
            $output .= '>' . $row['program'] . '</option>';
            echo $output;
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

*Just change **YOUR_DESIRED_VALUE** with your desired value*.

Reference: [**concatenation operator(.) in PHP**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for respon and your advice, ill try your answer first